# Cannot delete record in PostgreSQL table due to trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I would like to delete a record inside a table which have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.notify_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('watchers', 
    '{' ||
      '"table":"'    || TG_TABLE_NAME || '",' ||
      '"operation":"'|| TG_OP         || '",' ||
      '"row":'       || (select row_to_json(row)::varchar from (SELECT NEW.*) row) ||
    '}'
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.notify_trigger()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I tried to delete a record using `delete from test_notify where id = 1277`, it returns an error like this:

```
ERROR:  record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT pg_notify('watchers', 
    '{' ||
      '"table":"'    || TG_TABLE_NAME || '",' ||
      '"operation":"'|| TG_OP         || '",' ||
      '"row":'       || (select row_to_json(row)::varchar from (SELECT NEW.*) row) ||
    '}'
  )"
PL/pgSQL function notify_trigger() line 4 at PERFORM

********** Error **********
```

On the `test_notify` table I have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER watched_table_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON public.test_notify
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.notify_trigger();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote that trigger obviously made a mistake: `NEW` is not defined in `ON DELETE` triggers.

The best solution is to drop the trigger and re-create it with `ON INSERT OR UPDATE`.

To temporarily keep triggers from firing, you can set `session_replication_role` to `replica`. Be warned that that also disables foreign key constraints and therefore can only be changed by superusers.